# How to calculate resistors for an optocoupler?

Tags: resistors, mains, opto-isolator, math, esp32

I am a self-learner (for now) on electronics. I am trying to understand how to calculate resistor values when using an optocoupler and an ESP32

For my little project I want to sense several 220v wires with an ESP32.
For that I was thinking in using these components because they seem to have protection/isolation and they will reduce the things I need to do with high voltage:

[image]

Explanation:

1. 220VAC input get transformed into 5V by using an RAC05-05SK (or similar): [datasheet](https://www.distrelec.ch/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/RAC05-05SK_480_eng_tds.pdf)
2. An optocoupler isolates the power supply. I was checking the K847PH: [datasheet](https://www.distrelec.ch/Web/Downloads/14/_e/ai631214_e.pdf)

Now I need to calculate the values of the resistors keeping in mind safety and efficiency.

**Emitter resistor**

If I understood the optocoupler concepts correctly, I need about 10mA at 5v to get 100% CTR:
[image]

The worse case of Forward V. for the led is 1.6v:
[image]

So the resistor math would be:

[image]

My questions:

1. Are my calculations correct?
2. Can I connect 3.3v directly into the ESP32, or Do I need a resistor (or pull down resistor) If yes, how do you calculate the value of that resistor?

Thank you!

Comment: Why the psu module and an optocoupler? The psu gives you isolation probably better than the optocoupler. Normally for sensing mains you would use an optocoupler and a capacitive dropper.

Comment: my (beginner) logic was that since the input is coming from a different power supply, I had to either use an optocoupler or connect all GND together. For the latest one I have no clue if there is any risk or anything I have to do when connecting many GND together, so I thought it was going to be safer to do it this way. I will look into the capacitive dropper solution, no clue what it is. Thanks!!

Comment: You may never get 100% CTR. {low yield) You must define specs for input+ output tolerance and linear or saturate at <20% of linearCTR

Comment: For the psus, you would connect the gnds together. When in doubt, try to find a commercial piece of equipment that does something similar to what you want. See how they solve the problem and learn from it.

Comment: Sorry @Tony, I don't understanding your comment. Do you mean that I should calculate for < 1mA? (20% in the chat)

Comment: Vce(sat) is usually defined when current ratio is only 10% of the max hFE for Vce=5V  .. No I meant you must define V,I,R for inputs and outputs and 8 mA in seems to be optimum. So if using as a detector switch  with CTR min =0.2 AT VCE=5 V then at Vce(sat) or <0.8V you may use 20% of 0.2 of 8mA or 4% of 8mA for the output current.  But if you allow Vol= 2V max for a 5V logic"0" you must consider worst case tolerances and get  linear gain instead of saturated gain

Comment: I.e. CTR is not constant for Vce< 1~ V